# Send directX11 Rendering Data to client without rendering actually in server side

Tags: c++, directx-11

I have a windows application developed with directX11. While Creating SwapChain we set  **sd.OutputWindow = hwnd** and **sd.Windowed = true** In **DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC** descriptor. the output is shown to output window.

I want to keep this app on a server. Instead of rendering the output in server pc I want to send the render data to the client and do rendering in client side. That means:

1. There will be no rendering in server side.
2. Frame data will be sent client side. it will do the rendering.

Is it possible? If yes, then how can I achieve it?

Comment: D3D11 has no client server model. What you can do is just sending app-specific data and render according to that.

Comment: any workout possible? @Ralidex

Comment: Send your non-dx11 specific data and render according to that

Comment: In that case don't we need another rendering engine in client side? I don't want that

Comment: That's not possible, nothing's builtin for that. What you can do is duplicate server's output using Duplication API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi1_2/nn-dxgi1_2-idxgioutputduplication copy the bits on your client (any type of client on any OS, using any network protocol you like) and render them there. Companies make a living on this (playing games remotely).

Comment: Thanks @Saimon Mourier. I am new to directX11. can you provide any example link of implementation?

Comment: The official sample for using Duplication API (and rendering frames on screen) is here: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/DXGIDesktopDuplication there's none for remoting the frames.